# how to remove part of string from url for webalizer

Tags: url-rewriting, apache2, web-analytics, webalizer

On my site, I use version-strings in the URL, for example:

```
www.mydomain.com/images/image.v723484872.jpg
```

In the HTTP config, I rewrite the URL so that the version string is cut of.

How can I track the rewritten URL in Webalizer?

Thank you
Oliver

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mod Rewrite Env Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930431/mod-rewrite-env-variables)